# vertically align list items inside div

Tags: css

I've been trying to get this nailed for ages but can't seem to figure it out. I just need the text aligned horizontally and vertically in the center of each `<ul>` but it just isn't happening. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joso157/ds827wnd/)

Where am I going wrong?

```css
#HomeRight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0;
}

#HomeRight ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%; 
  display: table;
} 

#HomeRight li {
  display:table-cell;
  float:left;
  width:120px;
  height:25%;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="HomeRight">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/ds827wnd/1/?

Comment: Note that if you write `float` your `display` property will be transformed to `display: block`, so your `display:table-cell` desn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code it may help you.

```css
#HomeRight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 0;
}

#HomeRight ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%; 
  display: table;
} 

#HomeRight li {
  display:table-cell;
  float:left;
  width:120px;
  height:25%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="HomeRight">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly, what I was aiming for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe flex will be better solution than table

```
#HomeRight ul {
width:100%;
height: 100%;   
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ds827wnd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#HomeRight {
position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
top: 120px;
right: 0;
}
#HomeRight ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
} 
#HomeRight li {
  list-style: none;
width:120px;
height:25%;
text-align:center;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
border: 1px solid transparent;
background-clip: padding-box;
}
#HomeRight li:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 1px;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="HomeRight">
<ul>
<li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/ds827wnd/3/